# WebGL Spotlight

Tags: javascript, webgl, light

I have to add a spotlight to my rotating cube so this is my code:

```js
"use strict";

var canvas;
var gl;

var numVertices  = 36;

var texSize = 256;
var numChecks = 8;

var program;

var texture1, texture2;
var t1, t2;
var normalsArray = [];

var dirLightPosition = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
var dirLightAmbient = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 );
var dirLightDiffuse = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
var dirLightSpecular = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

var posLightPosition = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
var posLightAmbient = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 );
var posLightDiffuse = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
var posLightSpecular = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

var materialAmbient = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
var materialDiffuse = vec4( 1.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0 );
var materialSpecular = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
var materialShininess = 20.0;

var spotLightPosition = vec4(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0 );
var spotLightAmbient = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 );
var spotLightDiffuse = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
var spotLightSpecular = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
var spotLightDirection = vec4(-0.5,1.0,2.0,1.0);
var lCutOff=0.867;


var c;

var flag = true;

var image1 = new Uint8Array(4*texSize*texSize);

    for ( var i = 0; i < texSize; i++ ) {
        for ( var j = 0; j <texSize; j++ ) {
            var patchx = Math.floor(i/(texSize/numChecks));
            var patchy = Math.floor(j/(texSize/numChecks));
            if(patchx%2 ^ patchy%2) c = 255;
            else c = 0;
            //c = 255*(((i & 0x8) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x8)  == 0))
            image1[4*i*texSize+4*j] = c;
            image1[4*i*texSize+4*j+1] = c;
            image1[4*i*texSize+4*j+2] = c;
            image1[4*i*texSize+4*j+3] = 255;
        }
    }

var image2 = new Uint8Array(4*texSize*texSize);

    // Create a checkerboard pattern
    for ( var i = 0; i < texSize; i++ ) {
        for ( var j = 0; j <texSize; j++ ) {
            image2[4*i*texSize+4*j] = 127+127*Math.sin(0.1*i*j);
            image2[4*i*texSize+4*j+1] = 127+127*Math.sin(0.1*i*j);
            image2[4*i*texSize+4*j+2] = 127+127*Math.sin(0.1*i*j);
            image2[4*i*texSize+4*j+3] = 255;
           }
    }

var pointsArray = [];
var colorsArray = [];
var texCoordsArray = [];

var texCoord = [
    vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(0, 1),
    vec2(1, 1),
    vec2(1, 0)
];

var vertices = [
    vec4( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 )
];

var vertexColors = [
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // black
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // yellow
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // green
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // blue
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // magenta
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 )   // cyan
];

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;
var axis = xAxis;

var theta = [45.0, 45.0, 45.0];

var thetaLoc;

function configureTexture() {
    texture1 = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture1 );
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, texSize, texSize, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image1);
    gl.generateMipmap( gl.TEXTURE_2D );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                      gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    texture2 = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2 );
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, texSize, texSize, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image2);
    gl.generateMipmap( gl.TEXTURE_2D );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                      gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
}

function quad(a, b, c, d) {

     var t1 = subtract(vertices[b], vertices[a]);
     var t2 = subtract(vertices[c], vertices[b]);
     var normal = cross(t1, t2);
     var normal = vec3(normal);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[0]);
     normalsArray.push(normal);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[b]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[1]);
     normalsArray.push(normal);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[2]);
     normalsArray.push(normal);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[0]);
     normalsArray.push(normal);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[2]);
     normalsArray.push(normal);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[d]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[3]);
     normalsArray.push(normal);
}

function colorCube()
{
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
}


function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    colorCube();

    var nBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, nBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(normalsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vNormal = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vNormal" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vNormal, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vNormal );


    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colorsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(pointsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    var tBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tBuffer);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(texCoordsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vTexCoord = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vTexCoord" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vTexCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vTexCoord );

    var dirAmbientProduct = mult(dirLightAmbient, materialAmbient);
    var dirDiffuseProduct = mult(dirLightDiffuse, materialDiffuse);
    var dirSpecularProduct = mult(dirLightSpecular, materialSpecular);

    var posAmbientProduct = mult(posLightAmbient, materialAmbient);
    var posDiffuseProduct = mult(posLightDiffuse, materialDiffuse);
    var posSpecularProduct = mult(posLightSpecular, materialSpecular);


    var spotAmbientProduct = mult(spotLightAmbient, materialAmbient);
    var spotDiffuseProduct = mult(spotLightDiffuse, materialDiffuse);
    var spotSpecularProduct = mult(spotLightSpecular, materialSpecular);




    configureTexture();

    gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 );
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture1 );
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation( program, "Tex0"), 0);

    gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE1 );
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2 );
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation( program, "Tex1"), 1);

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "theta");

    gl.uniform4fv( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "dirAmbientProduct"),flatten(dirAmbientProduct) );
    gl.uniform4fv( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "posAmbientProduct"),flatten(posAmbientProduct) );
    gl.uniform4fv( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "spotAmbientProduct"),flatten(spotAmbientProduct) );
    gl.uniform4fv( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "dirDiffuseProduct"),flatten(dirDiffuseProduct) );
    gl.uniform4fv( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "posDiffuseProduct"),flatten(posDiffuseProduct) );
    gl.uniform4fv( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "spotDiffuseProduct"),flatten(spotDiffuseProduct) );
    gl.uniform4fv( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "dirSpecularProduct"),flatten(dirSpecularProduct) );
    gl.uniform4fv( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "posSpecularProduct"),flatten(posSpecularProduct) );
    gl.uniform4fv( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "spotSpecularProduct"),flatten(spotSpecularProduct) );
    gl.uniform4fv( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "posLightPosition"),flatten(posLightPosition) );
    gl.uniform4fv( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "dirLightPosition"),flatten(dirLightPosition) );
    gl.uniform4fv( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "spotLightPosition"),flatten(spotLightPosition) );
    gl.uniform1f( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "shininess"),materialShininess );
    gl.uniform1f( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "lCutOff"),lCutOff );
    gl.uniform1f( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
       "spotLightDirection"),spotLightDirection );




 document.getElementById("ButtonX").onclick = function(){axis = xAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonY").onclick = function(){axis = yAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonZ").onclick = function(){axis = zAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonT").onclick = function(){flag = !flag;};

    render();
}

var render = function() {
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    if(flag) theta[axis] += 2.0;
    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices );
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

// --- added to make it work ---

function initShaders(gl, vs, fs) {
  return twgl.createProgramFromScripts(gl, [vs, fs]);
}

function vec2(x, y) {
  return [x, y];
}

function vec3(x, y, z) {
  return [x, y, z];
}

function vec4(x, y, z, w) {
  return [x, y, z, w];
}

function subtract(a, b) {
  return a.map((a, ndx) => { return a - b[ndx];});
}

function mult(a, b) {
  return a.map((a, ndx) => { return a * b[ndx];});
}

function cross(a, b) {
  return [
    a[0] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1],
    a[2] * b[0] - a[0] * b[2],
    a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0],
  ];
}

function flatten(a) {
  return new Float32Array([].concat(...a));
}
init();
```

```html
<button id = "ButtonX">Rotate X</button>
<button id = "ButtonY">Rotate Y</button>
<button id = "ButtonZ">Rotate Z</button>
<button id = "ButtonT">Toggle Rotation</button>


<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute  vec4 vColor;
attribute  vec2 vTexCoord;
attribute  vec3 vNormal;

uniform float shininess;

uniform vec4 posLightPosition;
uniform vec4 posAmbientProduct, posDiffuseProduct,      posSpecularProduct;

uniform vec4 dirLightPosition;
uniform vec4 dirAmbientProduct, dirDiffuseProduct,      dirSpecularProduct;

uniform vec4 spotLightPosition;
uniform vec4 spotAmbientProduct, spotDiffuseProduct,spotSpecularProduct;
uniform vec4 spotLightDirection;
uniform float lCutOff;



varying vec4 fColor;
varying vec2 fTexCoord;

uniform vec3 theta;

void main()
{
    // Compute the sines and cosines of theta for each of
    //   the three axes in one computation.
    vec3 angles = radians( theta );
    vec3 c = cos( angles );
    vec3 s = sin( angles );

    // Remeber: thse matrices are column-major
    mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
        0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0,
        0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
        0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

    mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
        s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );


    mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
        -s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    vec3 N=normalize((rz*ry*rx*vec4(vNormal,0)).xyz);

    // positional light
    vec3 pos=-(rz*ry*rx*vPosition).xyz;
    vec3 posLight=posLightPosition.xyz;
    vec3 posL=normalize(posLight-pos);
    vec3 posE=normalize(-pos);
    vec3 posH=normalize(posL+posE);
    vec4 posAmbient=posAmbientProduct;
    float posKd=max(dot(posL,N),0.0);
    vec4 posDiffuse=posKd*posDiffuseProduct;
    float posKs=pow(max(dot(N,posH),0.0), shininess);
    vec4 posSpecular=posKs*posSpecularProduct;
    if(dot(posL,N)<0.0){
    posSpecular=vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    }

    // directional light
    vec3 dirLight=dirLightPosition.xyz;
    vec3 dirL=normalize(dirLight);
    vec3 dirE=normalize(-pos);
    vec3 dirH=normalize(dirL+dirE);
    vec4 dirAmbient=dirAmbientProduct;
    float dirKd=max(dot(dirL,N),0.0);
    vec4 dirDiffuse=dirKd*dirDiffuseProduct;
    float dirKs=pow(max(dot(N,dirH),0.0), shininess);
    vec4 dirSpecular=dirKs*dirSpecularProduct;
    if(dot(dirL,N)<0.0){
    dirSpecular=vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    }


    //spotlight
    vec3 spotLight=spotLightPosition.xyz;
    vec3 spotL=normalize(spotLight);
    vec3 spotE=normalize(-pos);
    vec3 spotH=normalize(spotL+spotE);
    vec3 spotD=spotLightDirection.xyz;
    vec4 spotAmbient=spotAmbientProduct;
    float spotKd=max(dot(spotL,N),0.0);
    vec4 spotDiffuse=spotKd*spotDiffuseProduct;
    float spotKs=pow(max(dot(N,spotH),0.0), shininess);
    vec4 spotSpecular=spotKs*spotSpecularProduct;
    if(dot(spotL,N)<0.0){
    spotSpecular=vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    }
    float lEffect= dot(normalize(spotD), normalize((spotL+spotE)));
    if(lEffect>lCutOff)
    {
    vec4 ambient=posAmbient+dirAmbient+spotAmbient;
    vec4 diffuse=posDiffuse+dirDiffuse+spotDiffuse;
    vec4 specular=posSpecular+dirSpecular+spotSpecular;


    fColor = ambient+vColor*(diffuse+specular);
    fColor.a = 1.0;
    }
    else{
    vec4 ambient=posAmbient+dirAmbient;
    vec4 diffuse=posDiffuse+dirDiffuse;
    vec4 specular=posSpecular+dirSpecular;


    fColor = ambient+vColor*(diffuse+specular);
    fColor.a = 1.0;

        }

        fTexCoord = vTexCoord;
    gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * vPosition;
    gl_Position.z = -gl_Position.z;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

varying vec4 fColor;
varying  vec2 fTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D Tex0;
uniform sampler2D Tex1;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = fColor*(texture2D(Tex0, fTexCoord)*texture2D(Tex1, fTexCoord));

}
</script>

<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="256" height="256">
</canvas>
```

So I computed tha angle between the spotlight direction and the vector to light source from vertex and if this angle is greater than the cutoff angle defined by the spotlight I compute the three products for the Phong lighting model.

Where am I wrong?

EDIT: MAIN PART OF THE QUESTION

HTML

```
//spotlight
        vec3 spotLight=spotLightPosition.xyz;
        vec3 spotL=normalize(spotLight);
        vec3 spotE=normalize(-pos);
        vec3 spotH=normalize(spotL+spotE);
        vec3 spotD=spotLightDirection.xyz;
        vec4 spotAmbient=spotAmbientProduct;
        float spotKd=max(dot(spotL,N),0.0);
        vec4 spotDiffuse=spotKd*spotDiffuseProduct;
        float spotKs=pow(max(dot(N,spotH),0.0), shininess);
        vec4 spotSpecular=spotKs*spotSpecularProduct;
        if(dot(spotL,N)<0.0){
        spotSpecular=vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
        }
        float lEffect= dot(normalize(spotD), normalize((spotL+spotE)));
        if(lEffect>lCutOff)
        {
        vec4 ambient=posAmbient+dirAmbient+spotAmbient;
        vec4 diffuse=posDiffuse+dirDiffuse+spotDiffuse;
        vec4 specular=posSpecular+dirSpecular+spotSpecular;


        fColor = ambient+vColor*(diffuse+specular);
        fColor.a = 1.0;
        }
        else{
        vec4 ambient=posAmbient+dirAmbient;
        vec4 diffuse=posDiffuse+dirDiffuse;
        vec4 specular=posSpecular+dirSpecular;


        fColor = ambient+vColor*(diffuse+specular);
        fColor.a = 1.0;

            }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var spotLightPosition = vec4(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0 );
var spotLightAmbient = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 );
var spotLightDiffuse = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
var spotLightSpecular = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
var spotLightDirection = vec4(-0.5,1.0,2.0,1.0);
var lCutOff=0.867;
```

Comment: uh, there is a lot going on here, it would be nice if you could set up a fiddle or pen

Comment: @palihead I'm a newbie in WebGL so I don't know what you are talking about, sorry! By the way, the main part of this topic is the section about the spotlight, I copied the whole code to make things clearer!

Comment: try to set up a "working" demo in here, much easier to debug:
https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: the only part that doesn't work is the spotlight, I tested the other part and it's all right! I will edit the post adding the main part of the code to focus on!

Comment: I edited to make the code work as a snippet and supplied the missing functions (assuming I got them correct). The code you posted even with the fixes didn't run because this line `vec3 N=normalize((rz*ry*rx*vNormal).xyz);` tried to multiply a vec3 `vNormal` by mat4s which doesn't work in WebGL. I'd be curious to know which book or website this code is based on.

Comment: @gman Thank you! I will modify the snippet as soon as possible! By the way, I just need to know if the theory behind the use of the spotlight is correct, this is the main problem

Comment: UPDATE: if i delete the "if(lEffect>lCutOff)", the spotlight works as a positional light so I assume that with the "if" construct the code runs always the "else" part and it doesn't compute the part within the "if". By the way, I can't still find what's wrong with the code :_(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gl.uniform1f( gl.getUniformLocation(program,
   "spotLightDirection"),spotLightDirection );
```

It's not a float but a 4-D vector so it should be `gl.uniform4fv`.

Answer (score 0):

Specular really doesn't work well with per-vertex lighting, particularly for a coarsely-vertex'd model like the cube here. It's possible that it simply doesn't look like you're expecting, when done per-vertex. With high shininess, you will basically never see specular highlights, since the evaluation of "how shiny should this pixel be" is done only at the vertex pixels, and linearly interpolated for all non-vertex pixels.

You can however test if the math is at least close by using shininess=0.0, which degenerates specular shading into diffuse shading.

Comment: Is it possible to add a button that switches from Gouraud model to Phong model in order to see the differences?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need two different pairs of shaders for this.